# android webview file download

Tags: android, file, background, download, webview

I want to download file from the internet that has loaded into the webview and i also want to know the file size and other information after downloading the file and the downloading process should be in the back ground that user doesn't get idea about the file downloading process how it can be possible from the android activity?